# Network request started failing in production app with No valid NAT64 prefix error over WIFI but works on mobile data, Android only

Tags: android, react-native

We started getting a `Network Request Failed` error in our production app when users try to login on WiFi, mobile data never has this issue. It occurs on most but not all WiFi networks. We have pushed no changes to our app recently and it only occurs on Android. Pertinent logcat message is `No valid NAT64 prefix`. Any ideas what could happening?

Comment: I got the same issue. After publishing the app to Play Store.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `usesCleartextTraffic` to `true` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` worked for me.

Add it in the `application` tag.

> [Cleartext Traffic Error](https://blog.usejournal.com/6-daily-issues-in-android-cleartext-traffic-error-52ab31dd86c2)
>
> Cleartext is any transmitted or stored information that is not
> encrypted or meant to be encrypted. When an app communicates with
> servers using a cleartext network traffic, such as HTTP, it could
> raise a risk of eavesdropping and tampering of content

Comment: My issue turned out to be from our host. They switched over their DNS provider and messed up something during the migration.